# sed/awk + regex delete duplicate lines where first field matches (ip address)

Tags: awk, sed, ip, match

I need a solution to delete duplicate lines where first field is an IPv4 address.For example I have the following lines in a file:

```
192.168.0.1/text1/text2
192.168.0.18/text03/text7
192.168.0.15/sometext/sometext
192.168.0.1/text100/ntext
192.168.0.23/othertext/sometext
```

So all it matches in the previous scenario is the IP address. All I know is that the regex for IP address is:

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

It would be nice if the solution is one line and as fast as possible.

Comment: reader, What does a 'duplicate' mean to you? i.e. since you specifically mentioned about matching IP addresses, it appears to me that you want to keep only 1 line per IP address. Is this correct? If not, then like @jcollado mentions, you should just use sort.

Comment: @ArjunShankar I guess he might want to remove duplicated lines, only if the $1 is ip address. so if there are two(+) lines like "abcdefg", they won't be removed. but this is just my guess.

Comment: @Kent: You could be right. Our confusion basically occurs because *all* lines in the example are IP addresses *and* there are no real duplicates except matching IPs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, the file contains lines **only** in the format you show, i.e. first field is always IP address, you can get away with 1 line of awk:

```
awk '!x[$1]++' FS="/" $PATH_TO_FILE
```

EDIT: This removes duplicates based **only** on IP address. I'm not sure this is what the OP wanted when I wrote this answer.

Comment: +1 for shortest solution that preserves the original order as well.

Comment: +1 no matter how OP define his "duplicated lines", this solution could be extended easily to match his needs. the classic !a[$n]++ usage to remove duplicates.

Comment: the solution is perfect! exactly what i needed! thank's alot for reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to preserve the original ordering, one way to do this is using `sort`:

```
sort -u <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

The awk that ArjunShankar posted worked wonders for me.

I had a huge list of items, which had multiple copies in field 1, and a special sequential number in field 2.  I needed the "newest" or highest sequential number from each unique field 1.

I had to use sort -rn to push them up to the "first entry" position, as the first step is write, then compare the next entry, as opposed to getting the last/most recent in the list.

Thank ArjunShankar!