# Keep only the line that is latest in the file and is a duplicate based on two fields

Tags: awk

This is related to the questions

- [awk - Remove line if field is duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604088/awk-remove-line-if-field-is-duplicate?rq=1)
- [sed/awk + regex delete duplicate lines where first field matches (ip address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257883/sed-awk-regex-delete-duplicate-lines-where-first-field-matches-ip-address)

I have a file like this:

```
FOO,BAR,100,200,300
BAZ,TAZ,500,600,800
FOO,BAR,900,1000,1000
HERE,THERE,1000,200,100
FOO,BAR,100,10000,200
BAZ,TAZ,100,40,500
```

The duplicates are determined by the first two fields. In addition, the more "recent" record (lower in the file / higher line number) is the one that should be retained.

What is an awk script that will output:

```
BAZ,TAZ,100,40,500
FOO,BAR,100,10000,200
HERE,THERE,1000,200,100
```

Output order is not so important.

Explanation of awk syntax would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (tac and GNU sort):

```
tac file | sort -sut, -k1,2
```

Comment: Ok, you demonstrated a solution that doesn't even use awk, and now I know about `tac` and some `sort` options that weren't obvious. Winner.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) : we just need to feed an array with a key combined with the 1st and the 2nd columns and the rest as values :

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1","$2]=$3","$4","$5}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' OFS=, file.txt
BAZ,TAZ,100,40,500
HERE,THERE,1000,200,100
FOO,BAR,100,10000,200
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate or link to an explanation of arrays in awk and how they help solve this problem?

Comment: An associative array have unique keys by nature. That's all the magic. Since we keep only the latest values, we just need to iterate over the lines and @the end, display the array line by lines